# "your voice starts very suddenly"?

Tags: phrase-request

I don't know much about microphones and audio programs, but I think everybody knows this slight problem that sometimes appears in recordings when you don't hear anything in the background during the breaks, it's like the microphone turns itself off when you stop talking. After that you start talking again and your voice *appears very suddenly*? Is this a correct way to explain this problem?

I framed some sentences that should convey this message. Which of them are correct and is there a better possibility?

1. Your voice appears very suddenly. (Not sure)
2. Your voice starts very suddenly. (Probably not)
3. Your voice sounds very abruptly. (Probably not)

I can't think of an alternative way to say this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as ***cutting in*** and when the recording stops before the speaker has really finished speaking it is said to have ***cut out***.

I might say of a bad phone or radio connection, "I can't understand you. Your voice keeps *cutting in and out*."

I am a little disappointed that [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cut+out) does not have an explicit entry for this exact condition, but it does have this entry:

> **cut out**  1. To remove by or as if by cutting.

This can make sense if you think about a recording on magnetic tape being *cut* with scissors and spliced together at a different position.

I might offer the definition:

> x. a loss of signal due to a fault in transmission or reception. *The voice on the radio kept cutting out whenever we went under a bridge.*

The situation you describe (where the voice cuts in suddenly) is likely due to a feature of the recording device where it does not record or transmit until it detects a sound loud enough to be recorded.  OF course it takes the device a moment to hear the voice and decide to start recording and by that time one or more of the first syllables will have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

For audio that's missing a section or abruptly cuts in and out, you can also use the terms "clipped" or "choppy". For coming back in, I like your choice of "abruptly."

Conversationally, if you're talking about making an audio recording I might say:

> When you start talking again it's a rather abrupt change. It might help to fade the audio in and out a bit so it doesn't sound so choppy.

Or

> Your voice comes in again rather abruptly. Can you fade it in to make the transition more gradual?

What's happening is that the microphone (or mixer, or software)  ["attenuates"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attenuate) (decreases) the input signal if it falls below a certain strength, in order to decrease unwanted background noise. The opposite case, when audio peaks above a desired level, can be "clipped" so as not to become distorted. These can also be affected with "compression" or "noise gates" that squeeze or boost an input signal that is above/below a certain frequency or amplitude. The "transition" or "decay" can be adjusted to create a more gradual change.

Comment: Actually, *clipping* happens on the other end of the scale- when the signal amplitude is **larger than** the dynamic range of the recorder or amplifier.  In clipping, the signal peaks are cut off or *clipped* (Imagine a mountain with its top chopped off)

Comment: Noted - was trying to cover both w/a single explanation & it didn't really work. Thanks